# Why is "Use Native Window" not the default in Vivaldi, and what does it actually do?

Tags: vivaldi

I thought I was going insane because Vivaldi by default (and after looking through all its settings) does not let me open new empty tabs by middle-clicking on empty parts of the tab bar, which all logic dictates is sane and correct.

Then, after reading through a lengthy discussion thread where the developers seemed to use every excuse in the book to avoid implementing this for some reason, somebody mentions that you can simply enable the "Use Native Window" setting, which I did immediately to try it out.

And now it works.

Huh?

Why is this not the default? And what exactly makes the "window" (the entire application, presumably?) more "native" if this option is checked?

There's got to be some weird downside which I've not yet encountered. I can't notice anything visually or behaviourarly different except that opening tabs now works correctly.

PS: I tried at length to register an account at the Vivaldi forum but not a single e-mail address (which is required) I entered was accepted, so I eventually gave up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vivaldi Help](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/tabs/windows/)
describes it as:

> Enable Native Window in *Settings > Appearance > Window Appearance*,
> tick the box for Use Native Window and restart the browser.
>
> Using the Native window allows you to:
>
> - Integrate Vivaldi with the rest of your operating system’s user interface;
> - Use OS-based window controls;
> - Display the Active Tab’s full title;
> - Make use of macOS’ Split View feature.

This means that when enabling this option, Vivaldi screens may look and
behave like any other native application on your operating system.
When disabled, the screens might look and behave differently than
what you are used to.

Why it is not the default I can only guess, but perhaps that the
developers wanted the default to always work correctly, in case
their adaptation to the native operating system was incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, but the last thing you mention seems to contradict the explanation?

Comment: Right, I got it reversed..

Answer (score 0):

FYI in case somebody needs this

enabling Native Window on Vivaldi solved full screen flickering, at least with Intel UHD. I also disabled VESA FPS gain in the Intel Command Centre, not sure if that also helped since it by itself wasn't the problem, but not enabling it since I don't want FPS gain (the feature description says at expense of tearing)